# Obtener datos de múltiples consutas MySQL y que las mismas se vayan guardando en una sola matriz. JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench, netbeans-8.2

El objetivo de esto es que se haga una consulta con dos componentes de fechas. Pero luego viene lo engorroso, si es que se puede decirle así.

Primero lo que hago es hacer una consulta del cual me devuelve **el/los datos**, que lo guardo en un arraylist, y que con esos mismos datos los utilizo para hacer otra consulta del cual para hacer la selección lo inserto dentro de un bucle for. De ahí es donde se van a hacer las múltiples consultas, y que de acuerdo a esos, los guardo en una **matriz** los datos obtenidos.

Aca es mi problema, porque al estar en un bucle se va hacer las consultas que sean necesarias pero no consigo que la matriz guarde todos los datos que se han obtenidos dichas consultas, no digo que las guardan mal sino que al estar en un ciclo for, la matriz obtendra los datos de la ultima iteracion, lo que por ende las mismas iteraciones anteriores se pisa o se sobre escribe en la matriz, que es lógico estoy consciente de ello pero me di cuenta al final que lo termine haciendo todo el código **(perdón por mi ignorancia)**.

**Pido su ayuda de que forma se puede guardar todos los datos de las consultas de acuerdo a la cantidad de datos que adjunto un array-list y que los mismos al final se guarden en una sola única matriz**.

El código que hice:

```
String[] columnasdetalle = {"IDDETCOMPRA", "IDCOMPRA", "IDINSUMO", "NRO FACTURA COMPRA", "INSUMO", "PRECIO", "CANTIDAD"}; // columnas de la tabla
                        ArrayList<String> nrosfacturas = busquedacompra.NroComprasFechas(fecha1, fecha2); // consulta que despues uso sus datos para las multiples consultas
                        int reg = busquedacompra.DevolverRegistros("detallescompras"); // cantidad de filas que tendran
                        Object[][] guardardatos = new Object[reg][columnasdetalle.length]; // length = cantidad de n posiciones que tendran una fila de la matriz
                        for (int i = 0; i < nrosfacturas.size(); i++) {
                            Object[][] datos = busquedacompra.MostrarDatosDetallesComprasNroFactura(nrosfacturas.size(), nrosfacturas.get(i)); // esto es un metedo que utilizo para el llenado de la tabla con los datos obtenidos del array
                            guardardatos = datos;
                            i++; // incremento para saber si hay mas de un dato del array
                            while(nrosfacturas.size() > i) { // si hay mas datos, ahora lo condicion de consulta con el ciclo while
                                datos = busquedacompra.MostrarDatosDetallesComprasNroFactura(nrosfacturas.size(), nrosfacturas.get(i));
                                guardardatos = datos;
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        datosdetallecompra = guardardatos; // lo guardo en matriz de tipo Object
                        datosdetalle = new DefaultTableModel(datosdetallecompra, columnasdetalle); // lo guardo en DefaultTableMode
                        jTable2.setModel(datosdetalle);// finalmente se lo incorpora a la tabla con su datos y sus columnas.
```

Paso explicar como se obtiene los datos del método MostrarDatosDetallesComprasNroFactura() :

Primero cargo los datos desde el paquete del controlador con el siguiente método:

```
public Object[][] MostrarDatosDetallesComprasNroFactura(int reg,String nrofactura) {
        String[] columnas = {"iddetallecompra", "idcompra", "idinsumo", "NroCompra", "descripcion", "Precio", "Cantidad"};
        return sql.DatosDetallesComprasVentas(columnas, reg,"select d.iddetallecompra,c.idcompra,i.idinsumo,c.NroCompra,i.descripcion,d.Precio,d.Cantidad from compras c LEFT JOIN detallescompras d on c.idcompra=d.idcompra LEFT JOIN insumos i on i.idinsumo=d.idinsumo where d.activo=1 and c.NroCompra like '%"+nrofactura+"%' order by c.NroCompra desc");
    }
```

Luego utilizo en el método desde la clase de inyecciones SQL, con el siguiente método que aca obtengo los datos que requiero (acá se entenderá los datos que use del método anterior):

```
public Object[][] DatosDetallesComprasVentas(String colName[], int reg, String sql) {

    Object[][] data = new Object[reg][colName.length];
    Object datos[] = new Object[colName.length];
    try {
        ps = con.conectado().prepareStatement(sql);
        res = ps.executeQuery();
        int s = 0;
        while (res.next()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < colName.length; i++) {
                datos[i] = res.getObject(colName[i]);
                data[s][i] = datos[i];
            }
            s++;
        }
        ps.close();
        res.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Desde ya Muchas gracias por su ayuda!, esto me tiene dias en no poder resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

En la siguiente sección de código

```
for (int i = 0; i < nrosfacturas.size(); i++) {
  Object[][] datos = Busquedacompra.MostrarDatosDetallesComprasNroFactura(nrosfacturas.size(), nrosfacturas.get(i));
  guardardatos = datos; // <-- Aca el error, cada vez que ingresa al for borra los datos anteriores
  i++; 
  while(nrosfacturas.size() > i) { 
    datos = busquedacompra.MostrarDatosDetallesComprasNroFactura(nrosfacturas.size(), nrosfacturas.get(i));
    guardardatos = datos; //Aca igual
    i++;
  }
}
```

Deberia hacer una copia del array con la clase Arrays (Arrays.copyOf o Arrays.copyOfRange)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: hola isaac! he investigado las dos maneras de copiar y me quede con el Arrays.copyOf. Lo hice en mi codigo pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo se pisa las iteraciones anteriores y toma el ultimo :( no se si yo lo estoy aplicando mal , te lo muestro:

Comment: `while (i < nrosfacturas.size()) {
                                    Object[][] guardardatos = busquedacompra.MostrarDatosDetallesComprasNroFactura(nrosfacturas.size(), nrosfacturas.get(i));
                                    arraynuevo = Arrays.copyOf(guardardatos, nrosfacturas.size());
                                    i++;
                                }`  Muchas gracias por tomar tu tiempo en resolver mi problema!

Comment: Hola Exe, Há pensado en cambiar la forma de almacenar las consultas?? Entiendo que las consultas son homogeneas (tienen las mismas columnas). El problema con Arreglos es que al momento de declararlos se declaran con tamaño fijo, por lo cual debe tener en cuenta cual es el indice del último elemento ingresado por cada consulta, y a partir de ahí empezar a guardar los nuevos datos de la nueva consulta. Puede colocar un ejemplo de como usted desea ver la salida y así poder mirar como solucionar su incidente.